# Fill input field when an item has changed in a drop down menu (html,javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get acquainted with javascript and how to use it with html. What i want to do is very simple, when a value has changed in a dropdownmenu id like to fill an input field with a string.

This is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="field_id" placeholder="Using..." style="width: 400px">
    <select style="width: 180px" onchange="Test()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        {% for stuff in stuffs%}
        <option value="{{stuff}}">{{stuff}}</option>
        {% endfor %}                    
    </select>
</div>
```

And the javascript in the same document:

```
<script>
    function Test()
    {
      document.getElementById(field_id).text = "asdsads";
    }   
</script>
```

Why wont the input field be filled with the string "asdsads"?

Comment: Have you [checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) Remember: `document.getElementById` takes a `'string'`.

Comment: try document.getElementById("field_id").text = "asdsads";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the parameter to `getElementById` as String:

```
document.getElementById("field_id").value = "asdsads";
```

Watch for the quotation marks around `field_id`.

In your code the `field_id` is an (undefined) variable. You should see an error / warning in the Javascript console of your browser.

And second: to set the value of an input field you need to set the `value` attribute, not the `text` attribute.

Here is a working fiddle with your example: https://jsfiddle.net/oapzL020/

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account that the input element should be initialized and tested for value using `value` attribute:

```javascript
document.getElementById("field_id").value = "some value"
```